# Simpleform can't get code to generate user error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

When someone enters a negative number I would like an error to display on the form. I am using simple_form. My browser is Chrome.

```
<%= f.input :payment_amt, error: 'Number must be positive', label: "Refund Amount", :input_html => { min: '0', step: 'any' } %>
```

Comment: Please show the complete form *and* the element that you want the message to appear in.

Comment: You can use 'f.error :payment_amt', but you'll have to 'validate' it on the model level

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.error :payment_amt %>
```

Use this right underneath your input field and it will display an error on submission.